# AutoCompleteTextField: How can one animate the hiding/showing of the suggestion list?

Tags: autocomplete, codenameone

I would like the suggestion list to appear/disappear with a vertical slide effect. As it is now, it merely pops in and out of view. Is there a built-in way to achieve this, or do I have to write my own component class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AutoCompleteTextField` is pretty old by now and predated some of the builtin functionality that would have allowed you to do that. I would just write my own `TextField` with `DataChangeListener` and use an `InteractionDailog` for the popup. It can animate showing/hiding.

Comment: Ok, I'm on it. The list items in the InteractionDialog are drawn with a dim, light grey color while I'm typing, presumably because the dialog hasn't got focus. Is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: It might be the style of the buttons or labels you added just use a different UIID for them and style that with the colors you want.